# What is the correct Spanish translation of "I don't Speak Spanish"?

Tags: traducción, gramática, español-neutral

How do I correctly say "I don't speak Spanish" in Spanish (not just in Latin America but also in Spain). Google translate suggests "Mi no habla espanol" but I have been told that that is incorrect and the correct form in fact is "No hablo espanol". I'm confused, are they both acceptable?

Comment: I have just tried and Google Translator offers me "Yo no hablo español" and "No hablo español", both perfectly valid. Their AI algorithm can be trolled sometimes if feeded with invalid data, maybe you just tried at the wrong moment and afterwards the error was detected and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

La forma correcta es

> (yo) no hablo español

"[Mi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P9rNqLB%7CP9tBea9%7CP9vG3X8)" es un adjetivo posesivo que tiene el significado de "mío" (*mine* en inglés).

"[Yo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cCEHAgu)" es un pronombre personal (stands for *I* en inglés)

"Hablo" es la conjugación en primera persona del singular de indicativo, (I speak) mientras que "habla" no es una conjugación de primera persona. Puede ser tercera de presente de indicativo ("él habla") o segunda de imperativo ("habla tú").

---

And for those who prefer it, here is an English version of this answer:

The correct form is

> (yo) no hablo español.

"Mi" is a possessive adjective used to talk about "my" something, or something that is "mine."

"Yo" is a personal (subject) pronoun (*I* in English).

"Hablo" is the first person singular conjugation of the verb "hablar," in the present tense (indicative).  "Habla" wouldn't be correct for this.  It could be the third person conjugation.  Or it could be the informal imperative (ordering someone to talk: "Talk!").

Comment: Rough translation of Diego's answer (but my Spanish is pretty awful):

The correct form is: (yo) no halo español.
Mi is an possessive word that means "mine" in English.
Yo is a personal pronoun, meaning "I" in English.

Hablo is a conjugation in singular first person.

Comment: @米凯乐, It is encouraged that questions get more than just answer. Sometimes it is difficult to see how you could explain something better than that answer that is already there, but it may not take much to make things clearer for the person asking. Of course, plagiarism is something that should be avoided, but I think that you could use my answer as a starting point or reference, and give it a try explaining it with your own words in English. You'll probably would make a much better answer than mine, because it would be easier for you to relate to what that person might be having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

> (Yo) no sé hablar español.

Esto no es una traducción directa pero significa lo mismo. "Sé" es la conjugación en primera persona del singular de indicativo del verbo "saber"